# What is the need to reset bold <b> or italic <i> HTML tags?

Tags: html, css

Following a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751679/what-could-cause-a-bold-tag-b-to-be-ignored#comment12405173_9751679) I just asked, what is the need for a `reset.css` to cancel the effect of bold `<b>` or italic tags `<i>`? What is this good for? What issue does it solve? What would be wrong with using `<b>` in HTML?

I am asking this question, because I am using a delivered `reset.css` and I want to get rid of this normalization. But is this safe? Is there a corner case I am missing?

Comment: `<b>, <i>` and `<u>` are style information and not content or structural information. It's better to define these styles outside of HTML with CSS, but nothing is _wrong_ with it. -- I don't understand what your question exactly is. There may be some reasons for this, but I don't know the intensions and purposes within drupal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of using CSS browser reset code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370294/whats-the-purpose-of-using-css-browser-reset-code)

Comment: @Smamatti I get your point, if you create an answer, I'll approve it.

Comment: @RobW I disagree, reset is useful in general, but this question relates to few tags only.

Comment: @Smamatti Don't worry, it is not a Drupal related issue.

Comment: @JVerstry Thanks for your appreciation, but I'll stick to a comment. It more or less common practice to use CSS instead of these tags, but this isn't ot may not be the purpose of reset CSS rules/files. I don't think this really answers your question.

Comment: Using `reset.css` for years I've only learned yesterday that it cancels mentioned tags with `b, u, i { font: inherit }`. This caused me some headache and I am glad that it is discussed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<b>` and `<i>` tags make the text appear bold and italic respectively, but semantically they are classed as presentational tags, therefore the effect would be best replicated with the CSS styles of font-weight and font-style. If the passage of text suggests areas of importance, they should be highlighted with the `<strong>` or `<em>` tags, which basically do the same job as `<b>` and `<i>`, but also make the world a nicer place. In other words, it has to do with the semantics of the underlying code which also affects, among other things, screen readers.

Comment: Ok, I get the intention behind this reset, though I think it is overkill (but that's me).

Answer (score 3):

There is no good reason. In general, reset.css is advertized as eliminating browser inconsistencies. It might also be said to remove unexpected default styling, such as some odd browser possibly using top and bottom padding (instead of top and bottom margin) on headings, so that when your style sheet tries to specify vertical spacing around heading, the effects aren’t what you expected.

None of this applies to canceling the bolding of `b` and the italics of `i`. There is nothing unexpected with such rendering; it is part of the meaning of the tags, and it is consistently applied by all browsers that can do bolding and italics in the first place. The only reason for resetting this would be an intent of defeating the intentions of the document’s author. The ideological principle “presentational markup is *bad*” might explain this; Erix Meyer’s [original article on CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/) seems to allude to that: he appears to want to think that no markup as such has any impact on rendering but the author must style everything.